# Instantiate a class defined in the server from the client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

I have two C# services I use wcf for communication between us (with NetNamedPipeBinding). The wcf configuration is ok and communication work.

we can schematically see the application like that :

```
Server :  
interface myInterface  
 //interface description
Class myclass : myInterface  
 //Methode and properties  

client :   
 System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<myInterface> myChannelFactory = null;  
 myInterface myService;  
 myChannelFactory = new System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory<myInterface>("ClientService");  
 myService = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

with wcf I can call "myclass" methods because *myInterface* know this methods but I want to instantiate "myclass" in the client service like

```
client :  
myclass Newclass = new myclass;
```

actually it's impossible because myclass code is in the Server service and wcf know only the interface information

is it possible with another wcf implementation ? If no with another technology ?
I hope I'm not the first who want to do that :D

Comment: What you seem to be proposing breaks the tenants of SOA and web services.  The client should not be aware of or even care about the implementation details of the service.  Why do you want the client to be able to instantiate the service class?

Comment: The code you say you want will instantiate the object on the client.  Is that what you want, or should WCF still be involved?

Comment: It is possible. I don't know if it is possible using WCF, probably - yes. But read on **custom serialization**. Your server and client  must know assembly in which `myclass` lives. Hopefully, this is a thin assembly full of `models` or `requests/responses`. Now, this mean that your client can't be web browser on desktop. Or, it can but IE only with a lot of headache. And I am not even sure if it will be supported in the future for IE.

Comment: @Tim I want to build an application with different module (one central module + one for dialog with equipment... (all in the same machine). For exemple my central module need to instantiate an "equipment class".

Comment: @bmm6o can you precise your question maybe my Tim comment response give you enough information (if not please tell me)

Comment: @T.S. I hope it's possible ;D. IF WCF can't do this I can use other technology it's new application and I have free hand to chose the technology. But actually WCF is the best wait that I find to implement windows service communication. Have you any idea of other technology or architecture that can I use ?